# Why does this python logic statement behave opposite to my expected behavior?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean-logic, python-2.x

I run the following in the Python interpreter:

```
  some_list = []
  methodList = [method for method in dir(some_list) if (callable(getattr(some_list, method)) and (not method.find('_')))]
```

What I would like is to get a list of all the names of methods for a particular object, **except** methods that are named with underscores, i.e. `__sizeof__`

This is why I have the if statement nested in my above code:

```
 if (callable(getattr(some_list, method)) and (not method.find('_')))
```

But the contents of `methodList` are:

`['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']`

Indeed, the precise opposite of what I'm expecting.

Shouldn't `not method.find('_')` only return true when the `method` string fails to contain the string `'_'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the documentation for [`str.find`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

> Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found, such that sub is contained in the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 if sub is not found.

The expression `method.find('_')` returns -1 if an underscore is not found, and 0 if it starts with an underscore. Applying `not` means that only methods that start with an underscore will give `True` (because `not 0` is `True`).

Use `'_' not in method` instead.

Comment: Better would be `'_' not in method`

Comment: Thanks! Clears things up. It's a strange world moving to python from perl.

Comment: I think `startswith('__')` would be better than `in` if you try to find the magic methods.

Comment: Or `not method.startswith('_')` if you want to exclude magic methods and private methods.